# initialize array inside struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, header-files

```
struct myStruct
{   
    short int myarr[1000];//want to initialize all elements to 0
}
```

How do I initialize the array?

I tried doing `short int* myarr[1000]={0}` inside the struct but it's wrong. How can I do this? I don't mind doing it in the implementation file. This struct is contained in a header file.

Answer (score 3):

Use the universal initializer: `{0}`.

The universal initializer works for anything and initializes the elements to the proper 0 (`NULL` for pointers, `0` for ints, `0.0` for doubles, ...):

```
struct myStruct example1 = {0};
struct myStruct example2[42] = {0};
struct myStruct *example3 = {0};
```

---

Edit for dynamically allocated objects.

If you're allocating memory dynamically use `calloc` rather than `malloc`.

```
p = malloc(nelems * sizeof *p); /* uninitialized objects; p[2] is indeterminate */
q = calloc(nelems, sizeof *q);  /* initialized to zero; q[2] is all zeros */
```

*With realloc (and possibly other situations) you need to `memset`.*

Answer (score 1):

If it is declared out of a function (not on the stack), the whole struct will be zeroed at compile time.

Otherwise, you can use `memset` after declaring it.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize an instance of the struct with {0}, this will zero your array as well. Alternatively, use memset as NKCSS demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

int's arn't reference types, don't they get initialized after allocating memory for your structure?

You could just do this:
memset(&myStruct, 0, sizeof(myStruct));